# How do I automatically change the lock screen image?

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

Is it possible to automatically change background image of the lock screen.

For example having it pick a random image from my `Pictures` library, or some online source each time it's displayed or maybe changing per day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

[Bing My Lockscreen](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-GB/app/bing-my-lockscreen/7e1f890f-8960-43e5-a258-58ba3eeb1163) (currently released with more updates coming) is doing exactly this with the Bing Photos.

[image]

> Bing My Lockscreen allows you to select from the eight most recent
>   Bing images and quickly select which of them to set your lock screen
>   to use.
>
> In addition Bing My Lockscreen allows you to automatically have your
>   lockscreen updated daily with the latest image from Bing - thus
>   ensuring a constant supply of inspiring and interesting new content
>   for you!

Note: This is [a submission to the apptivate.ms](http://apptivate.ms/apps/4/bing-my-lockscreen) contest.  Help support him and give him a "thumbs up"